# cant set OUTPUT to return a table from another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure which returns a temp table to another stored procedure. However, I cannot seem to be able to set a table as an output variable. For instance:

```
   @t table(ID int) output
```

as a parameters does not work. However the following does not complain:

```
   @t int output
```

Is there a way to get one stored procedure to obtain a table generated by another stored proceedure? Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No.

You could pass the name of the created table from one `Stored Procedure` to another and then in the second `SP` you can use the name to query thru the table.

Comment: Is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by using a User Defined Table Type. All you need to do is

1. Create a User defined Table Type.
2. Create your first Stored Procedure to Accept a Table Type variable.
3. In your second procedure declare a Table Type variable, populate it with the data you want and call the first procedure by passing in the Table Type variable.

Here is a sample code.

1) Create the User Defined Table Type. Under the Programmability -- > Types -- > User Defined Table Types  -- > Right click to create your table type

```
CREATE TYPE [schemaname].[Ttype] AS TABLE 
(
    EmployeeID int,
    EmployeeName varchar(100),
)
GO
```

The above type is just an example, put in the columns that you require in it. Here Ttype is the Name of the TableType (you can name it as per your convenience)

2) Create your first stored procedure that will accept the Table type as variable so that you can use it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [schemaname].[StoredProcName]
@TableType Ttype READONLY
AS
BEGIN
     -- Just an example on how to use the TableType.

    INSERT INTO TableName(EmployeeId,EmployeeName)
    SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeName FROM @TableType

END
GO
```

The above Stored Procedure accepts a Table Type variable. The Ttype indicates that the @Tabletype variable is user defined table type. The READONLY indicates that no DML operations can be performed on the Table type parameter.

3) Now, create your second procedure that will pass the Table Type parameter to the above procedure created.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [schemaname].[StoredProc2Name]

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Table as Ttype 

    INSERT INTO @Table(EmployeeID,EmployeeName)
    SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeName FROM schemaname.Employees

    EXEC [schemaname].[StoredProcName] @Table


END
GO
```

In the above SP, you declare a variable named @Table which is of the Table Type (Ttype). Now you populate it with the data you need and then call the first procedure by passing in the @Table variable.